# Make bootstrap typeahead autocomplete clickable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, autosuggest, clickable, typeahead

I am using Bootstrap Typeahead which I got it from GitHub 1891669. It brings up the suggested words  but would like to fix two issues:

[The example is here](http://qaamoos.com/test01/)

- When I click on the item it just prints 0 in text field. What do I do so it prints the full word?
- How can I make each suggest clickable with the suggest word?

I looked at the code. The Typeahead javascript has the following:

```
      $.fn.typeahead.defaults = {
     source: []
     , items: 8
     , menu: '<ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu"></ul>'
     , item: '<li><a href="#"></a></li>'
     , onselect: null
     , property: 'value'
     }
```

so I would like to make `href="mylink.php?term=**theword**"`
so how can I insert suggested word in place of **theword** in href above so when user clicks on the link it just doesn't fill the text field but rather goes to `mylink.php` with the parameter.

In that example I have inserted the Typeahead javascript with bootstrap.js. To make it simple for you to view the Typeahead java script [here](http://qaamoos.com/test01/bootstrap-typehead.js).

thanks

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I also want this kind of solution

Answer (score 0):

You're using an older version of Typehead (v2.0.0), which has been updated to fix that issue. Try using the latest version instead: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Comment: I just checked the examples in your provided link and there is no bootstrap. Plus it doesn't have the "source:" field

Comment: This is a stand-alone version of Typehead that's likely going to be integrated with future versions of Bootstrap. It works with Bootstrap just the same: [If you want to use this with a project like Bootstrap, all you have to do is include the JavaScript file for typeahead.js after Bootstrap’s JavaScript file.](https://blog.twitter.com/2013/twitter-typeaheadjs-you-autocomplete-me). Looks like they've renamed `source` to `local`.

Comment: I visited the page but it talks all about "prefetch" and no php example. could you look at this:


        <body class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="well span4">
            <input id="typeahead" type="text" class="span4" placeholder="Search cities..." autocomplete="off" />
                </div>
            </div>
    
        <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#typeahead').typeahead({
                ajax: 'suggest.php',        
        itemSelected: displayResult
            });
        });